# Как составить программу в соответствии с временной сложностью алгоритма O(2*n) и O(n)?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация, сложность

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale>
#include <cstdlib> //для генерации рандомных чисел
#define SIZE 28

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    /* Алгоритм:
    int min=a[0], k=0;
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
    if (a[i]<min) 
        min=a[i];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        if (a[i]==min) 
            k++;
    */  
    /* 
        кол-во минимальных элементов в целочисленном массиве
        при временной сложности алгоритма = O(2*n)
    */ 

    int Arr[SIZE];
    srand(time(0));  

    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)                  // генерация 28 шт случайных чисел, от 0 до 100
        {
            Arr[i] = rand()%100;
            cout << Arr[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";


    int min = Arr[0], k = 0;                    // реализация алгоритма

    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
        if (Arr[i] < min) 
            min = Arr[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        if (Arr[i] == min) 
            k++;

    cout << "количество минимальных элементов = " << k << endl;
    cout << "\n\n";

    /* 
        найти кол-во минимальных элементов в целочисленном массиве
        при временной сложности алгоритма = O(n)
    */ 


    getch();
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Сформулируйте точнее, что вы хотите. Что должнаделать программа, что она делает, что нет, в чем вопрос. И учтите, что O(2n) и O(n) - это эквивалентные записи. Как и O(3n) или O(123n+18ln(n))...

Comment: Harry, прикреплена картинка. В ней более наглядно задан вопрос. Там указан алгоритм, который определяет количество минимальных элементов в целочисленном массиве. Мне нужно составить программу так, чтоб временная сложность составленного кода соответствовала O(2*n), и еще одну программу чтоб временная сложность соответствовала O(n).   Программа была составлена. Успешно запускается в Dev-C++, но не понятно какую она выполняет временную сложность. Может, чтоб определить временную сложность, нужно создать счетчик, подсчитывающий количество итераций?

Comment: Понятно, что так аффтары как бы делают посыл "как объединить два цикла в один", но вообще формулировка задачи уровня БЕГN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По дополненному вопросу замечу только, что преподы в последнее время стали совсем из рук вон плохи - видимо, пошли в преподы птенцы гнезда ЕГЭшного... Написали ерунду...

Поскольку я понимаю, *что на самом деле* они хотели спросить, то вот вам ответ...

```
int min = a[0], k = 1;
for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    if (min > a[i])
    {
        min = a[i];
        k = 1;
    }
    else if (min == a[i]) ++k;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Этот код будет соответствовать: и для O(2*n), и для O(n), так как они эквивалентны?

Comment: Уверен, преподы хотели не два отдельных прохода по массиву, а один (хотя теоретически сравнений все равно в наихудшем случае будет выполняться два). Но сформулировали они этот вопрос математически некорректно, так как константные множители в понятие O() не входят.

Comment: @Harry а как тогда правильнее сформулировать задачу?

Comment: @Learpcs Я бы спросил, как двухпроходный алгоритм преобразовать в однопроходный. Ведь не факт даже, что получится уменьшить количество сравнений!

Answer (score 4):

В исходной программе написано два цикла. В первом мы находим минимальный элемент, а во втором подсчитываем количество элементов, равных минимальному.

Ваша задача — сделать то же самое в одном цикле. Например, так:

```c
int min = a[0], k = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  if (a[i] < min) {
    min = a[i];
    k = 1;
  }
  else if (a[i] == min)
    k++;
}
```

Здесь мы сравниваем каждый следующий элемент с последним найденным минимальным. Если новый элемент меньше минимума, то это новый минимум. Сохраняем его в качестве такового и устанавливаем счётчик `k` в 1 — то есть найден один минимальным элемент.

Если новый элемент равен минимуму, то это ещё одна копия минимума, увеличиваем счётчик.

В любом другом случае это элемент больше минимума, ничего делать не надо.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Mark Shevchenko. А если бы временную сложность попросили сделать O(1), то код пришлось делать другим? Ведь O(2n) и O(n) - это эквивалентные записи. А O(1) это не эквивалентно и функция на графике по-другому растет.

Comment: А O(1) вы никак не получите. В случае произвольного (неупорядоченного) массива сложность меньше O(n) не получится, потому что надо просмотреть все элементы массива.

Comment: @Muriam, Harry прав, O(1) для произвольных данных никак не получить. Наименьшее, что я могу придумать, это O(log N) на упорядоченном массиве. В начале массива будет минимальный элемент, а двоичным поиском можно найти следующий элемент, который больше него.

Comment: Mark Shevchenko, Harry,  Если у меня есть другая программа. Реализует сумму элементов последовательности. Каждый элемент последовательности вычисляется, как результат в таблице умножения на 3. То есть формула: n , 2*n, …, m*n. Где n = 3, m = 10. Мне здесь надо составить алгоритм так, чтоб сложность алгоритма была О(1). Скажите, здесь неуместно использовать цикл for? Здесь надо использовать структуру данных Список для создания программы?

Comment: @Muriam, O(1) означает, что цикла не должно быть вообще, должно быть одно выражение. Цикл это O(N)..Конкретно в вашей задаче речь идёт о сумме элементов геометрической прогрессии, для этого есть формула. Наберите в гугле *сумма геометрическая прогрессия*, разберитесь с формулой, и подставьте в неё свои значения 3 и 10.

Comment: Вам просто надо вычислить `n*m*(m+1)/2`, каковое выражение **при любых** m и n вычисляется за одно сложение, 2 умножения и одно деление, т.е. время вычисления **не зависит** от n и m, а значит, равно O(1).

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вы оба не просто подсказали с кодом, но и объяснили, почему так происходит. Сложно выбрать лучший ответ. Вы помогли равноценно.